# why does sharepoint remove <img src="data:image/jpg;base64 from "Publishing HTML" fields

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

When embedding `<img src="data:image/jpg;base64 .....` in the HTML source of "Publishing HTML" field, you see the image in the edit form. after hitting save, the image is gone and the source just shows `<img alt= something`

Is there any way to override this behavior?
Is there an example of saving it in an image library?

Answer (score -1):

yea man. Why? LOL looking for a way for people to copy and paste easily to RTE.

Another workaround is to put the data into something like 'data-src' attribute and use js to move it later when rendering the rich text....
sad.